# Google Play Store behaving strangely: apps don't install

Tags: google-play-store

Lately, when I try to install apps from the GPS, the following things happen:

1. When I tap "install," the blue "waiting" bar shows up. (I don't know whether there's a better name for it.)
2. Instead of turning into a progress bar that shows the app downloading, the "waiting" bar just sits there. I eventually hit "stop".
3. When I go to the GPS on my computer, the apps I have unsuccessfully attempted to install show as installed, even though they're not. (And they don't show as installed on my phone.)

Has anyone seen this behavior before? What is the remedy?

EDIT. The phone is a Moto X, not rooted, on a cellular connection. It started maybe a week ago. I can't think of anything I might have done to provoke it.

Comment: A quick tip to help you write questions that people can understand and answer: don't abbreviate Google Play Store to GPS. GPS already means Global Positioning System, so you're likely to confuse readers.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with some more details? What phone do you have? Have you rooted it and/or disabled any built-in apps? What kind of internet connection is it on, and have you tried using a different connection?

Comment: Second both comments above. I was already wondering whether one can download apps via satellite #D Additionally, as you've mentioned "before": with your [edit], please include what you did "before" the problem started – or whether it was there from the very beginning.

Comment: Moto X, not rooted, on a cellular connection. Haven't tried wifi. The problem started maybe a week ago, with no instigation from me as far as I can remember.